# redis lua script call redis.call("ZREVRANGE", KEYS[1], start, end, 'WITHSCORES')

Tags: php, database, redis, phpredis

I use phpredis extension, and when I call:

```
redis.call("ZREVRANGE", KEYS[1], start, endPos, 'WITHSCORES')
```

in lua script, it returns

```
array(6) {
[0] =>
string(5) "10010"
[1] =>
string(2) "12"
[2] =>
string(5) "10012"
[3] =>
string(2) "-2"
[4] =>
string(5) "10011"
[5] =>
string(2) "-2"
}
```

actually I want to return associative array:

```
array(
"10010" => 12, "10012 => -2, ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the same thing using [PREDIS](https://github.com/nrk/predis) and it returns exactly the way you want it to.
You might want to try that..

```
include 'Autoloader.php';

Autoloader::register();

$redis = new Predis\Client(array(
    "scheme" => "tcp",
    "host" => localhost,
    "port" => 6379,
));

$scores = $redis->zrevrange('key','start','end',withscores);
```

Comment: I'm running lua scipt on redis server with phpredis extension, not just using a redis extension to get  data from zset.